# Disable and re-enable a javascript function using onclick events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out how I can disable a javascript function using an onclick event. I've just finished building a carousel with touch events. Now I'm creating another which enables or disables the carousel by onclick events.

Here is a sample of my code I've built. The function that I want to disable is the `touchCarousel` which controls the touch events.

The class `.slider-layout` enables the carousel while the class `.tile-layout` disable the carousel and transforms the layout in a card view layout

```js
var activeSlide = 0;
    $('.faculty-carousel').attr('data-slide', '0');
    
    
    
    $('.tile-layout').on('click', function() {
        $('.faculty-items').each(function() {
            $(this).addClass('tile-view');
        })
    })
    
    
    $('.prev').on('click', function(e) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    
        var carouselWrapper     = $(this).closest('.faculty-carousel'),
            facultyProfilePanel = carouselWrapper.find('.faculty-items li'),
            facultyProfileCount = facultyProfilePanel.length,
            viewPortSize        = $(window).width(),
            carousel            = carouselWrapper.find('.faculty-items'),
            position            = 0,
            currentSlide        = parseInt(carouselWrapper.attr('data-slide'));
    
        // Check if data-slide attribute is greater than 0
        if (currentSlide > 0) {
            // Decremement current slide
            currentSlide--;
            // Assign CSS position to clicked slider
            var transformPercentage = -1 * currentSlide / facultyProfileCount * 100;
            carousel.css('transform', 'translateX(' + transformPercentage + '% )');
    
            // Update data-slide attribute
            carouselWrapper.attr('data-slide', currentSlide);
            activeSlide = currentSlide;
        }
    });
    
    $('.next').on('click', function(e) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        // store variable relevent to clicked slider
    
        var carouselWrapper     = $(this).closest('.faculty-carousel'),
            facultyProfilePanel = carouselWrapper.find('.faculty-items li'),
            facultyProfileCount = facultyProfilePanel.length,
            viewPortSize   = $(window).width(),
            carousel = carouselWrapper.find('.faculty-items'),
            position = 0,
            currentSlide = parseInt(carouselWrapper.attr('data-slide'));
    
        // Check if dataslide is less than the total slides
        if (currentSlide < facultyProfileCount - 1) {
            // Increment current slide
            currentSlide++;
            // Assign CSS position to clicked slider
            var transformPercentage = -1 * currentSlide / facultyProfileCount * 100;
            carousel.css('transform', 'translateX(' + transformPercentage + '% )');
    
            // Update data-slide attribute
            carouselWrapper.attr('data-slide', currentSlide);
            activeSlide = currentSlide;
        }
    })
    
    
    function touchCarousel() {
        $('.faculty-carousel .faculty-items').each(function() {
    
            // create a simple instance
            // by default, it only adds horizontal recognizers
    
            var direction,
                touchSlider = this,
                mc = new Hammer.Manager(this),
                itemLength = $(this).find('li').length,
                count = 0,
                slide = $(this),
                timer;
    
            var sliderWrapper = slide,
                slideItems = sliderWrapper.find('li'),
                //slider = sliderWrapper.find('li'),
                totalPanels = slideItems.length,
                currentSlide = parseInt(sliderWrapper.attr('data-slide'));
    
            // mc.on("panleft panright", function(ev) {
            //   direction = ev.type;
            // });
    
            mc.add(new Hammer.Pan({
                threshold: 0,
                pointers: 0
            }));
            
            mc.on('pan', function(e) {
                var percentage = 100 / totalPanels * e.deltaX / window.innerWidth;
                var transformPercentage = percentage - 100 / totalPanels * activeSlide;
                touchSlider.style.transform = 'translateX( ' + transformPercentage + '% )';
                var sliderWrapper = $(e.target).closest('.faculty-carousel')
    
    
                if (e.isFinal) { // NEW: this only runs on event end
    
                    var newSlide = activeSlide;
                    if (percentage < 0)
                        newSlide = activeSlide + 1;
                    else if (percentage > 0)
                        newSlide = activeSlide - 1;
                    goToSlide(newSlide, sliderWrapper);
                }
            });
    
    
            var goToSlide = function(number, sliderWrapper) {
                if (number < 0)
                    activeSlide = 0;
                else if (number > totalPanels - 1)
                    activeSlide = totalPanels - 1
                else
                    activeSlide = number;
    
                sliderWrapper.attr('data-slide', activeSlide);
    
                touchSlider.classList.add('slide-animation');
                var percentage = -(100 / totalPanels) * activeSlide;
                touchSlider.style.transform = 'translateX( ' + percentage + '% )';
                timer = setTimeout(function() {
                    touchSlider.classList.remove('slide-animation');
                }, 400);
    
            };
        });
    }
    
    
    function panelSizing() {
    
        // var activeSlide = 0;
        // $('.faculty-carousel').attr('data-slide', '0');
    
    
        var viewPortSize        = $(window).width(),
            carouselWrapper = $('.faculty-carousel')
        ;
        
        //Set Panel Size based on viewport
    
        if (viewPortSize <= 1920 ) {
            var profilePanelSize = viewPortSize / 5
        }
    
    
        if (viewPortSize < 1024 ) {
            var profilePanelSize = viewPortSize / 4
        }
    
        if (viewPortSize < 768 ) {
            var profilePanelSize = viewPortSize / 3
        } 
    
        if (viewPortSize < 480 ) {
            var profilePanelSize = viewPortSize
        }
        
        carouselWrapper.each(function(){
            var wrapper = $(this);
            // wrapper.attr('data-slide', '0');
    
            var facultyPanel = wrapper.find('.faculty-items li'),
            profileCount = facultyPanel.length,
            // activeSlide         = 0,
            carousel            = wrapper.find('.faculty-items');
    
            carousel.outerWidth( profilePanelSize * profileCount );
            facultyPanel.outerWidth(profilePanelSize);
            carousel.css('transform', 'translateX(' + 0 + '% )');
        });
    }
    
    $('.tile-layout').on('click', function() {
        $('.faculty-items').each(function() {
            $(this).addClass('tile-view');
            $('.faculty-carousel .faculty-items').css('transform', 'translateX(' + 0 + '% )');
        })
    });
    
    $('.slider-layout').on('click', function() {
        $('.faculty-items').each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('tile-view');
        })
    })
    
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        panelSizing();
        touchCarousel()
    
    })
    
    $(window).on('resize', function(){
        panelSizing();
        touchCarousel()
    
    })
```

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
    a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
    del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
    small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
    b, u, i, center,
    dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
    fieldset, form, label, legend,
    table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
    article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
    figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
    menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
    time, mark, audio, video {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border: 0;
      font-size: 100%;
      font: inherit;
      vertical-align: baseline; }
    
    /* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
    article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
    footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
      display: block; }
    
    body {
      line-height: 1; }
    
    ol, ul {
      list-style: none; }
    
    blockquote, q {
      quotes: none; }
    
    blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
    q:before, q:after {
      content: '';
      content: none; }
    
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-spacing: 0; }
    
    .faculty-items.tile-view {
      display: flex !important;
      flex-wrap: wrap !important;
      width: 100% !important; }
    
    .faculty-items li {
      height: 100px;
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative; }
      .faculty-items li > a {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        user-drag: none;
        user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-drag: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none; }
    
    .faculty-items li:nth-child(odd) {
      background-color: grey; }
    
    .faculty-items li:nth-child(even), .faculty-items a:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: aqua; }
    
    .faculty-items {
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      right: 0;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s linear; }
    
    .faculty-carousel .controls {
      display: block; }
    
    /*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.js"></script>
    
    <div class="slider-layout">
        slider layout
    </div>
    
    <div class="tile-layout">
        tile layout
    </div>
    
    <div class="faculty-carousel">
        <ul class="faculty-items">
            <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
        </ul>
    
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="prev">
            prev
            </div>
    
            <div class="next">
            next
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="faculty-carousel">
        <ul class="faculty-items">
            <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 9</a></li>
        </ul>
    
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="prev">
            prev
            </div>
    
            <div class="next">
            next
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="faculty-carousel">
        <ul class="faculty-items">
            <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 9</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 10</a></li>
        </ul>
    
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="prev">
            prev
            </div>
    
            <div class="next">
            next
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Very simply, add a flag such as `is_enabled` and when they enable/disable, set `is_enabled` respectively then when they try to use the carousel check if your `is_enabled` flag is `false`, if it is `return false` so execution stops.

**Update**

By *flag* I simply mean a variable which has been created for the purpose of checking if a condition has been met, generally Boolean of a value.

**Example**

Simple example below of a click even being prevented by a flag.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p4cr1t8c/)

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, not yet familiar with adding flags `is_enabled`

Answer (score -1):

you can easy handle this issue with this code after you function see this codes

```
function disableClick() {
   document.getElementById('yourId you want disable on click').onclick = "";
}
```